# GROUP BY date column and then group by custom daytime

Tags: group-by, postgresql-13, jsonb

So I have to group a table according to the date and then the timeday when a product arrived, the timedays would be:

```
morning = [5, 6, 7 , 8, 9]
mid_morning = [10, 11]
midday = [12, 13, 14]
evening = [15, 16, 17 ,18 ,19, 20]
night = [21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE inventory (
      inventory_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
      arrive_date date NOT NULL,
      arrive_location character varying NOT NULL,
      thing_type integer NOT NULL,
      quantity integer NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO inventory (arrive_date, arrive_location, thing_type, quantity) VALUES
  ('2018-05-30 05:00:00-00', 'location_00', 3, 2)
, ('2018-05-30 06:00:00-00', 'location_00', 3, 8)
, ('2018-05-30 12:50:00-00', 'location_00', 5, 2)
, ('2018-05-30 13:40:00-00', 'location_00', 1, 3)
, ('2018-05-31 13:00:00-00', 'location_00', 4, 7)
, ('2018-05-31 18:00:00-00', 'location_00', 2, 3)
;
```

The desired result would be to have this table result:

| preprocess_id | arrive_date | arrive_timeday | arrive_location | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 2018-05-30 | 0 | location_00 | { "3": 10 } |
| 34 | 2018-05-30 | 2 | location_00 | { "5": 2, "1": 3 } |
| 36 | 2018-05-31 | 2 | location_00 | { "4": 7 } |
| 37 | 2018-05-31 | 4 | location_00 | { "2": 3 } |

The current [query fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9acac2150ec7d4854fa2ebff7710d8a) that I have only group by day, is it possible to have the date and then the daytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how `preprocess_id` was produced and how an actual hour was mapped to `arrive_timeday` in your desire result. Any way, you can use a `CASE` expression or a mapping table to map to the number.

Using `CASE` expression

```
SELECT arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location
     , jsonb_object_agg(thing_type, total_things)
FROM  (
   SELECT arrive_date
        , arrive_timeday
        , arrive_location
        , thing_type
        , sum(quantity) AS total_things
   FROM   (
       SELECT date_trunc('day', arrive_date) AS arrive_date
            , case 
              when extract(hour from arrive_date) in (5, 6, 7 , 8, 9) then 0
              when extract(hour from arrive_date) in (10, 11) then 1
              when extract(hour from arrive_date) in (12, 13, 14) then 2
              when extract(hour from arrive_date) in (15, 16, 17 ,18 ,19, 20) then 4
              when extract(hour from arrive_date) in (21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) then 8
              end arrive_timeday
            , arrive_location
            , thing_type
            , quantity
       FROM   inventory
   ) inv
   GROUP  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location, thing_type
   ) sub
GROUP  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location
ORDER  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location;
```

Using mapping table:

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE hour_mapping (
  hour_from integer NOT NULL,
  hour_to integer NOT NULL,
  timeday integer NOT NULL,
  descpt character varying NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO hour_mapping (hour_from, hour_to, timeday, descpt) VALUES 
  (5, 9, 0, 'morning')
, (10, 11, 1, 'mid_morning')
, (12, 14, 2, 'midday')
, (15, 20, 4, 'evening')
, (21, 23, 8, 'night')
, (0, 4, 8, 'night')
;
```

Query

```
SELECT arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location
     , jsonb_object_agg(thing_type, total_things)
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('day', arrive_date) AS arrive_date
        , m.timeday as arrive_timeday
        , arrive_location
        , thing_type
        , sum(quantity) AS total_things
   FROM  inventory inv, hour_mapping m
   WHERE extract(hour from inv.arrive_date) between m.hour_from and hour_to
   GROUP  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location, thing_type
   ) sub
GROUP  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location
ORDER  BY arrive_date, arrive_timeday, arrive_location;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5e878c9fea252a97e3ea14f45d016c50)